# Moto G USB Debugging Issues with Windows 7 64bit

Tags: android, debugging, android-4.4-kitkat

I tried to search if there are any suggestions but couldn't find enough hence this question to help me out.

I've installed Motorola USB Driver and enabled USB Debugging mode as well with MTP enabled.

The device shows as available in Eclipse for less than a minute and after that it gets back to offline mode. I tried to do ADB command like Kill-server and start-server but there is NO effect.

And it comes back to online after so many ON/OFFs and disable/enable the USB debugging/ disconnecting and reconnecting the USB cable or so again and after all these efforts, the device again stays in debug mode for the same <<1 min.

I also tried it with PTP mode as well but no use. Is this a known issue with MotoG or Am I doing something wrong?

My settings are like this under USB Debugging:

- Stay awake - On
- USB debugging - On
- Allow mock locations - On

Appreciate if somebody can guide me which will enable me to work with my MotoG and Android Programming...

Comment: I'd try a different USB cable. For example, I've had devices that didn't like cables that had a choke on them, while other devices seemed to require one (though, I'll admit it's been a while since I've run into that kind of thing). Also consider using Linux for Android development - ADB drivers on Windows seem to often be a finicky nightmare; on Linux they just work.

Comment: @Michael - I tried with different USB cable and looks a bit stable now. Let me observe for a day before I take a step to move to Linux environment. But from your suggestion, it seems to be a better option :) and I definitely Value it.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Michael, I've tried with a different USB cable and it looks stable as of now. Let me observe the behavior for a day before I conclude that it's working.

Unfortunately, While purchasing Moto G, it doesn't come out with a USB Cable as part of the accessories and hence we have to depend on market available cables.

As of now, I'm trying with a USB Cable which has come along with Sony Xperia.

Updating the answer:

After 24 hours of continuous usage - my MotoG runs like a charm in USG Debugging mode. Hence, accepting it as an answer in Windows 7 64 bit.

I'll switch to Linux soon...as per other suggestion.