# Android SDK not recognizing MOTO E

Tags: android, adt, android-4.4-kitkat, motorola-droid

My eclipse ABD is not recognizing my MOTO E phone.

i turned on the developer options and debugger options.

please help.

thanks

Comment: Which os you are using, pC

Answer (score 0):

Please check this : 
[Moto G USB Debugging Issues with Windows 7 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177366/moto-g-usb-debugging-issues-with-windows-7-64bit/24180815#24180815)

I had similar issues with Moto G and after good effrots, now it is smooth. And I believe same rules apply to Moto E as well. BTW, which OS are you working with ?

I believe you've installed, USB Driver and all the mandatory as required prior to hope to be visible in Eclispse IDE

Answer (score 0):

Download the MotorolaDeviceManager software. It contains USB drivers and software to connect your phone or tablet to your computer using a USB cable.

It's found it the most stress-free solution when I faced the similar problem.

Here are the download links

https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481
http://motorola-device-manager.software.informer.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this problem still exists but I've come up with a solution.

Just download the "ADB Driver Installer" from **adbdriver.com** and install it.

It worked for me in Windows 7 x86/64. I did face a problem in Windows 8 x64 though.

The link:
http://adbdriver.com/downloads/